# Who gets the bounty if placed on third party question, and the asker self-answers and accepts their own answer?

Tags: support, bounty

If I assign bounty on other person question and that person answers his question, and accept it as well; and there is another answer with higher score (also posted during the bounty period):

Who will get bounty and how much will it be if the bounty owner does not assign it manually?

Comment: You'll find out [3 hours from now](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52424724/how-to-implement-tablayout-iontabselectedlistener-ontabunselected-with-tabbedpag/52793890#52793890).

Comment: This is actually a really good question. I never thought of this

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you read the [help page](https://stackoverflow.com/help/bounty) carefully, this is actually quite clear:

- Since the question asker is not the one posting the bounty, acceptance is not taken into account.
- If the user who posts the bounty doesn't award the bounty explicitly, the highest scored answer (with a minimum of score 2) posted during the bounty period will automatically be awarded half the bounty amount.